# String comparison on Android Data Binding

Tags: android, data-binding, comparison, string-comparison

I'm trying to make a string comparison with android XML data binding, but I'm not having the right results.

Evaluating my expression in code, I try `notice.action == "continue"` and this is false. And in data binding, this is false too, of course.

```
android:textColor='@{ notice.action == "continue" ? @color/enabledPurple : @color/disabledGray}'
```

It only gets true when I do `notice.action.equals("continue")` by code. This is the intended behavior. My problem is that I can't accomplish this with data binding expressions, because it won't run methods like `equals`. What can I do to replace the comparison expression with another one that works?

I'm using [this guide](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/tools/data-binding/guide.html).

Edit:
I was wrong, methods are allowed in XML. Did it this way:

```
android:textColor='@{ notice.action.equals("continue") ? @color/enabledPurple : @color/disabledGray}'
```

Comment: Why do you say that it won't run a method like .equals()? Methods are supported in data binding expressions.

Comment: Re-reading the docs, I found it. I guess I past over it. Thank you for pointing this, I will try in my code!

Comment: Could you please share the code for using equals() in databinding

Comment: Of course. It's like this @anoopg87.

"android:textColor='@{ notice.action.equals("continue") ? @color/enabledPurple : @color/disabledGray}'"

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It can be do in two way :-

**1. First way inside xml :-**

```
    android:textColor="@{notice.action.equals(`continue`) ? @color/enabledPurple : @color/disabledGray }"
```

**2. Second way (programatically) Inside xml :-**

```
app:setColor="@{notice.action}" 
inside activity or custom class : -    
    @BindingAdapter("setColor")
        public static void setTextColor(TextView textView, String s) {

             Context context = textView.getContext();

        textView.setTextColor(s.equals("continue") ? context.getResources().getColor(R.color.enabledPurple) : context.getResources().getColor(R.color.disabledGray));
        }
```

Answer (score 9):

There is no need to import the String class into your layout file.

To check whether two strings have equal value or not **`equals()`** method should be used.

**`=`** is used to check the whether the two strings refer to the same reference object or not.

Solution:

```
android:textColor="@{notice.action.equals(`continue`) ? @color/enabledPurple : @color/disabledGray }"
```

Comment: This may throw  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException:  "String has already been defined as java.lang.String but trying to re-define as String"

Answer (score 5):

'continue' is char type, so it should be changed to String to compare with notice.action.

```
android:textColor="@{notice.action.equals(String.valueOf(`continue`)) ? @color/enabledPurple : @color/disabledGray }"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to add in xml

`<data> <import type="String"/> </data>`
It may help to resolve `.equals()`